# Rspec Controller Tests with an STI user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I'm attempting to write some controller specs for a sub controller, in this case Admin::UsersController

It has the basic set of CRUD actions.

my users_controller_spec.rb

```
describe Admin::CarriersController do
  before(:each) do
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
  end

  it "should have a current_user" do
    subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "assigns all users as @users" do
      user = create(:user)
      get :index
      assigns(:users).should eq [user]
    end
    it "renders the index view" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

Now the problem i'm running up against is the index action. My controller work and is a simple @users = User.all

Whats complicating things is my User table is STI so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Client < User
end
class Seller < User
end
```

My factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    sequence(:email) {|n| "test#{n}@test.com"}
    password "password"
    password_confirmation {|instance| instance.password }
    type "Seller"

    factory :admin do
      type "Admin"
    end

    factory :seller do
      type "Seller"
    end

    factory :client do
      type "Client"
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously the eq method is not working becuase RSpec has problems matching the class names in my assigns(:users) expectation.
My exact error is:

```
1) Admin::UsersController GET 'index' assigns all users as @users
     Failure/Error: assigns(:users).should eq user
       expected #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Client id: 1282, name: "Marks-Kozey", type: "Client"...]> to eq #<User id: 1282, name: "Marks-Kozey", type: "Client"...
```

Is my problem my factories? or am I testing incorrectly. This is my first time testing STI so any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Why not create a client via factory, instead of a user?

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing this splitting up the users factories into separate factories per user type but this seemed a hack as it doesn't represent proper STI, works now though

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the class symbol into the child factory, e.g.:

```
factory :client, class:Client do
  type "Client"
end
```

The factory-generated object should then be of type `Client` instead of `User`.